# Take a Screenshot, save it a specified place, with a timestamp based name and copy its filepath plus filename to clipboard

Tags: command-line, bash, clipboard, gnome-screenshot

I want to do below,

1. Take a Screenshot,
2. Save it a specified place,
3. Name it with a timestamp based string and
4. Copy its filepath plus filename to clipboard.

How can this be done?

Comment: `scrot` is a command line screenshot tool.

Comment: Your question seems unclear. Any screenshot tool in combination with common desktop tools can do this. What do you want to achieve? Do it automatically? From the command line? With a single click or keyboard shortcut?

Comment: @vanadium I figured it out with Vanadium's help. Thanks Mate. Install scrot and use, scrot '%s.png' -e 'mv $f </folder/to/save/image/> & echo $f' | tr -d '\n' | xclip -selection clipboard

Comment: @Sebastian Yes and it is done. See the previous comment. Thanks.

Comment: Feel free to write it out as an answer. It is perfectly fine on this site to answer your own question.

Comment: @vanadium Done. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@vanadium suggested me this fine command line tool called scrot and rest was easy to figure out. (Thanks to the example in scrot's online [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/scrot.1.html))

Putting it here, just in case someone might need it.

scrot -- is command line tool for taking screenshots. Install it.

```
sudo apt install scrot
```

Also, install these if you don't have them --> tr, xclip

```
sudo apt install tr xclip
```

Now make a text file. Write the below code into it.

```
#! /bin/bash

scrot '%s.png' -e 'mv $f </folder/to/save/image/> & echo $f' | tr -d '\n' | xclip -selection clipboard
```

</folder/to/save/image/> is the location where you want your images to get saved, once you take screenshots. You can change it to whatever you wish, any time.

Name it and save the file. Make it executable,

```
sudo chmod +x <filename>
```

Either add the file to your PATH or copy it to some folder on PATH.

After all this, bind this file to a keyboard shortcut.

Every time you launch the short-cut, it will save the Screenshot at the location in the file (you can keep changing the location in file as per your need) and put the fileName at your clipboard. (Super HANDY!!)

Feel free to ask any questions you might have.

P.S. I needed this to work with LaTeX in my own customized way.

Comment: Useful and specific answer! Feel free to also accept your own answer!

Comment: @vanadium Thanks. Done.